# Static friction and torque on decelerating wheel

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, friction, torque

I want to understand how static friction work when wheel is decelerating, it will increase torque or it will decrease torque of wheel? On picture I show how I understand it works(sorry for quality of this). It is right or I made some mistake? Thanks for answer!
[image]

Comment: In braking (deceleration) the torque applied to the wheel by the brake is counter-clockwise, not clockwise as shown. The counter clockwise torque results in the wheel applying the force Ft  on the road in the opposite direct shown, i.e., forward. Then per newtons third law the static friction force the road applies to wheel is equal and opposite to the applied force, or backward, causing deceleration.  So Ft in your diagram is the static friction force applied to the wheel, not the force the wheel applies to the road.

Comment: But what if we don't use brakes and wheel deceleration is caused only by static friction so Ft increase torque of wheel?

Comment: Static friction only exists in opposition to another force. If there are no torques or horizontal forces acting on the wheel, the wheel would continue to roll at constant linear and angular velocity without any friction.

Comment: I wondering about situation when we e.g. driving a car and than turn off engine and we have some torque on wheels, but we don't use brakes so static friction will be opposite direction to this shown on the picture or it is correct?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the wheel is rolling without slipping then the interaction with the ground cannot be described as only a force. The ground exerts both a force and a torque on the wheel.

The force causes the wheel to decelerate, so it is pointed backwards. As you note, a force pointed backwards produces a torque that tends to accelerate the wheel. Since the wheel is decelerating there must be a torque from the ground in the opposite direction of the torque from the torque produced by the decelerating force.

Where does this torque come from? Here is a close-up view of the contact patch. [image: Close view of contact patch] Note that the force is not exerted at a point, but over a patch, and note further that the force is asymmetric across that patch. There is more force in front of the axle than behind, which provides a torque in the opposite direction.

Thus, rolling resistance is more correctly thought of as a torque than as a force.